# Gerar documento .doc utilizando HTML para formatar texto e com rodapé fixo em todas ás páginas

Tags: php, html, microsoft-word

Estou com um grande problema para gerar um arquivo **.doc** específico.

O meu arquivo **.doc** possuí uma tabela bem complexa como cabeçalho do documento, mas este cabeçalho será feito na mão e não terá que repetir em todas as páginas. Como o cabeçalho é bem complexo só consegui fazê-lo em HTML utilizando a classe `clsMsDocGenerator` para gerar o arquivo **.doc**. O problema é que essa classe não me permite colocar rodapés fixos (rodapé normal do word).

Tentei o `phpWord` e o mesmo coloca o rodapé mas não ceita meu cabeçalho em HTML (string com tags HTML). Logo o problema é conseguir uma forma de gerar arquivos **.doc** com esse cabeçalho em HTML e com rodapé fixo em todas ás páginas.

Alguém sabe como fazer, ou tem uma outra forma de fazer isso e conseguir chegar no resultado esperado?

Comment: Leandro, bem vindo ao stackoverflow pt  faça um [TOUR](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) , e veja como criar perguntas  mais detalhadamente.

Comment: Leandro, tem que ser .doc? Se puder ser .PDF creio que teria mais recursos.

Comment: Sim, este é o problema, tem que ser .doc :(